# Why is my d3js map slow to load in Chrome and Safari?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, safari, d3.js

I've been playing with making a responsive D3 map.

When I load the map (http://bl.ocks.org/radiocontrolled/raw/7698088/) it's slow to load/there's a lag for displaying the map in Chrome and Safari.

Here's the gist, I'd be grateful for any help!

http://bl.ocks.org/radiocontrolled/7698088

Thank you.

Comment: You might be able to get better performance using canvas, see e.g. [here](http://geoexamples.blogspot.com/2013/02/mapping-with-d3js-canvas-or-svg.html).

Comment: Possibly because the map has some quite complex paths. I can't see exactly what the issue is, but there seems to be really large memory spike - when I look at the memory snapshot, the paths seem to take up a huge amount of RAM for what they are. Complex graphics *can* be more performant on canvas (though not if you write your canvas calls badly, mind)

Comment: @Lars and Jimmy -- 
Thanks for the suggestions on Canvas. For this though - Part of it was that I was using a GeoJSON that was way more complicated than I needed it to be. I ran canada.json through mapshaper, and that seems to have improved thing. http://www.mapshaper.org/

Comment: It's not so slow for me. The map isn't very complicated, and Canvas shouldn't be necessary in this case. It's better when you are redrawing the map all the time, for example, but this is not your case.